# element present but hidden selenium check

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How can I check if an HTML element is hidden (display:none:) with selenium IDE?

In my case the html is a button and I want selenium to announce me if the element is hidden.

If I use verifyElementPresent, selenium will find the element although is hidden.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use any derivation of the [`storeVisible`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeVisible) command.

Most notably, `assertVisible` and `waitForVisible` have been useful for me in the past.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I needed.  waitForVisible, waitForNotVisible

Comment: Then, how to use it. It's better to post a simple example in your answers, so that reader won't spend couple of minutes more searching for that `waitForVisible`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether a HTML button is hidden or not just use command verifyvisible

command:verifyVisible

Target:id of the button

if your button is visible it will not throw error but if it not visible it will throw error

Thank You.